# Azure Function Set Blob Output Filenamr

Tags: python, binding, azure-functions

I have a durable activity function which downloads a file from an api. The activity function receives the href for the file to download as an input.
I’d like to extract the filename part from the href and set this in the path parameter. E.g. container/directory/{filename}.txt

From the docs, I see that is possible to access input bindings but I cannot find and example for an activityTrigger.

I’m using the Python worker.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement ,

You can use `os.path.basename` as shown in below example:

`print(os.path.basename("https://example.com/file.html"))`

[image]

NOTE:- *There is no such output binding available as mentioned in this [***Open GitHub Issue***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/910) yet to use input binding please refer this* [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#example).

For more information please refer this [***GitHub|How to set Storage Blob Filename, Content-Type, etc. on output binding?***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/507)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up creating some functions using the azure storage library.